# undefined local variable or method `signin' for #<Class:0x31fa7f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have the following error in model class. How to approach such errors.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :signin
  validates :username, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    puts warden_conditions
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR 
            lower(email)= :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first
  end

end
```

I am new to rails and learning things by doing. How to `debug` such issues. If i get such error in model, where should i first look.

Comment: please puts output `warden_conditions` variable

Comment: you should find out why your Model does not contain the signin method

Comment: @Monk_Code: where does it print puts warden_conditions.

Comment: @emaillenin this method from `devise`, for auth by pair username and email or something else.

Comment: What is `signin?`. It does not seem to be a class method on your model (and you are executing it in a class context)

Comment: before `conditions = warden_conditions.dup`

Comment: This error states that `signin` is not defined in your scope. `signin` can be either a method or a variable. You need to provide more code in order to receive help

Comment: I have updated my entire user model class

Comment: @Monk_Code: where would it print, now in Js if i put console.log() it prints in browser console. but when i puts i dont know where it prints.

Comment: @theJava look my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method from `Devise`, for auth by pair username and email or something else.
You problem in `signin` variable i use `login` instead look my code:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      if login.start_with?('+')
        where(["phone = :value AND phone_confirm = :phone_confirm", { value: login.downcase, phone_confirm: true }]).first
      else
        where(["lower(email) = :value", { value: login.downcase }]).first
      end
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
```

Comment: Should variable name be a problem and also when you put puts warden_conditions where does it print?

Comment: i want look inside warden_conditions, this is hash with option for login. i wanna see console output from rails server. if you `puts warden_conditions` and run this method, you have see this in console.

Comment: can u tell me where to look for it. i mean if i put puts warden_conditions where does it print

Comment: in `rails server` output if it run.

Comment: Here is what it printed in rails server http://pastie.org/private/7g1n6tu31zevisohurqw

Comment: this is warden_conditions output `{"email"=>"some@gmail.com"}` line 8 in you paste

Comment: How do you say so? I mean i getting confused on printing the values to console.

Comment: can i print something like puts "Hello" + wardencondition

Comment: this is just for debbug your method, i use this always beyond [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry).

Comment: no you cant this raise errors because "Hello" is a `string` warden_conditions is a `hash`.

Comment: How do i combine both. I mean in other languages you can append a string so that you can know its printing your line correctly.

Comment: in ruby you can use `warden_conditions.inspect` or `warden_conditions.to_s` methods for conversion any object to string, and after use `puts("Hello" + warden_conditions.to_s)`

Comment: Great from yesterday i was struggling on this. either way... did u get any idea on where the issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50619/discussion-between-thejava-and-monk-code)

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor :signin` defines an accessor for instances of your class.

The problem is that you try to access it in a class method's scope so it is undefined. The functionality you want is to perform a query based on two parts:

- the warden_conditions
- username stuff

I would suggest implementing two new scopes (or one)

```
scope :warden_stuff -> { |conditions| where(conditions) } # which can be omitted
scope :user_stuff -> do |user| 
  where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email)= :value",
         { :value => user.downcase }])
end
```

and implement your method as

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions, user)
  warden_stuff(warden_conditions).user_stuff(user).first
  # or where(warden_conditions).user_stuff(user).first
end
```

so that it can be used as
`user = User.find_first_by_auth_conditions(the_conditions.dup, a_user)`

Comment: What is this warden_stuff and user_stuff and what is scope. The ruby thing is breaking my head.

Comment: You should read some of the documentation. Start here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Thanks,also i have been looking at their docs. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address can you explain me on how they are solving the same using the find_first_by_auth_conditions method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when studying through "Learning Devise for Rails" eBook.

**Problem**:

`singin` really is a local variable not defined, the way that is being called.

**Solution**:

`warden_conditions` is a hash which contains a signin key. Use this hash instead of the local variable. Correct code below:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => warden_conditions[:signin].downcase }]).first
end
```

**Notice**:
I removed the first `where` method because `signin` is not a column in the database. So, I figure it does not make sense to call this first `where` method.

I also removed `conditions = warden_conditions.dup`, since there is no need to .dup(duplicate) the *warden_conditions* hash, since there is no need to worry about his preservation in this particular case.

But be careful, if you pass more then one parameter through `warden_conditions` hash then you need to keep the first where and then you need to duplicate the hash so you can delete the `signin` key. Then use the second where for the backed up `signin` key.

For me this worked perfectly.